# MdDialogRef does not work as Modal dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have a the following typescript code for a simple dialog:

```
import {MdDialogRef} from "@angular/material";
import {Component, Optional} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
template: `
    <div class='panel-body' align="center">
            Your email address:<input #emailAddressInput>
           <button md-button (click)="dialogRef.close(emailAddressInput.value)">OK</button>
    </div>
`
})

export class EmailDialogContent {
    constructor(@Optional() public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<EmailDialogContent>) { }
}
```

to open the dialog i user:

```
    openSimpleDialog(): void {
    this.dialogRef = this._dialog.open(EmailDialogContent, {
        disableClose: false,
        width: '500px',
        position:{bottom:'100%', left:'710px', right:'100%'}});

    this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        console.log("email address:" + result);
    })

}
```

The problem is that my dialog does not behave as Modal dialog,
and i can continue click other things on my page when the dialog is open
and clicking outside the modal does not close the it

any Idea?

Comment: You should put a plunker. It can be lots of things. There should be some errors in your console

Comment: Looks like you have to set `disableClose` value to true.

Comment: disableClose=true does not help!

Comment: Did you import `MatDialogModule` in your @NgModule? Can you describe the problem in a little more detail?